# Room through DAO fails inside composable in NavHost

Tags: kotlin, android-room, composable

I have issues retrieving data from a db in Room.

Inside the navHost I get a list of all the elements from one table of the database (players of a team) and then pass the list to a composable containing a LazyColumn and a list ->

```
    composable(route = ClappsicScreen.Roster.name) {
        val players by viewModel.getPlayers().collectAsState(emptyList())
        /* Add Roster Page here */
        TeamScreen(
            players = players, // Datasource.playersList,
            dataUiModel = viewModel,
            onCardClick = {it->
                viewModel.setPlayerId(it)
                navController.navigate(route= ClappsicScreen.Player.name)
            }
        )
    }
```

Once an item in the list has been selected (player's card) I need to retrieve the item ID to query the DB to obtain exactly *that* item from the DB. with the same approach the DAO is not able to retrieve the player and crashes and no property delegate can be retrieved.

```
        composable(
            route = ClappsicScreen.Player.name
        ) {
            val playerId = viewModel.getPlayerId()
            val player by viewModel.getPlayer(playerId).collectAsState(initial = dbPlayer(id = playerId)) //val player here is THE initial dbPlayer, never retrieved the delegate correctly
            PlayerScreen(player =player) //this crashes later
        }
```

if I move to the top of the composable the getPlayer, the operation completes fine.

```
@Composable
fun ClappsicsApp(
    viewModel: DataViewModel = viewModel(factory = DataViewModel.factory),
) {
val player by viewModel.getPlayer(playerId).collectAsState(initial = dbPlayer(id = playerId))
```

but ofc the result is not updated.
Why the former code works and the latter no? How can I fix it?